# How to find the limit of an infinite recursion relation

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

The recursive relation is $f(n+1) = 2 + \frac{1}{f(n)} $, I would like to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  f(n)$$
given $f(1)=3$.

I tried to use [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) but it does not give me a definite value.

```
RSolve[{f[n + 1] - 1/f[n] == 2}, f[1] == 3, n]
```

Comment: Try this: `FixedPoint[2 + 1/# &, 3.]`. It applies the function repeatedly until the output doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you, FixedPoint worked!

Comment: @AnjanKumar - `FixedPoint[2 + 1/# &, 3.] // RootApproximant`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's much better.

Comment: You have incorrect syntax for `RSolve`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Version 11.2, you can use `RSolveValue` to obtain the answer as shown below
(unfortunately, earlier versions return `Indeterminate` for this input).

=================

```
RSolveValue[{f[n + 1] - 1/f[n] == 2, f[1] == 3}, 
f[Infinity], n]
(* 1 + Sqrt[2] *)

N[%]
(* 2.41421 *)

FixedPoint[2 + 1/# &, 3.]
(* 2.41421 *)
```

=====================

Hope this helps.

Devendra Kapadia,
Wolfram Research, Inc.

Answer (score 7):

It should be `RSolve` rather than `Rsolve` and the boundary condition must be inside the list of equations.

```
Clear[f];
eqns = {f[n + 1] - 1/f[n] == 2, f[1] == 3};

soln = RSolve[eqns, f, n][[1]];
```

Verifying that the solution satisfies the equations

```
eqns /. soln // Simplify

(*  {True, True}  *)

f[n] /. soln // FullSimplify

(*  1 + Sqrt[2] - (2 Sqrt[2] (1 - Sqrt[2])^n)/((1 - Sqrt[2])^n + (1 + Sqrt[2])^n)  *)

Limit[f[n] /. soln, n -> Infinity]

(*  1 + Sqrt[2]  *)

Limit[f[n] /. soln, n -> -Infinity]

(*  1 - Sqrt[2]  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
cp = {x, x} /. Solve[x == 2 + 1/x, x];
fp = cp[[2, 1]]
f[x0_, n_] := 
 Sequence @@ {{##}, {{##}[[2]], {##}[[2]]}} & @@@ 
  Partition[NestList[2 + 1/# &, x0, n], 2, 1]
Plot[{2 + 1/x, x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@cp}]
ListAnimate@
 Table[Plot[{2 + 1/x, x}, {x, 2.3, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[cp], Line[f[3, j]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {2.3, 2.45}], {j, 1, 5}]
```

[image]